# Project Euler # 19

Tags: python-3.x, calendar

The count is apparently wrong.  I am trying to find the number of Sundays falling on the first of month in the 19th century.

```
import calendar  
count=0  
for x in range(1900,2001):  
    for y in range(1,13):  
        if calendar.weekday(x,y,1)==6:  
            print(x,y)  
            count+=1  

print(count)
```

OUTPUT: 173
Answer is 171

Any clue why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

19th Century is 1800s and not the 1900s

So, replace your for-loop with
`for x in range(1800,1900):`

Comment: Also note that the last year of the century is XX99 (as shown in the answer code, but different in the question code)